# Force on suspension when hitting a step

Tags: dynamics

I'm trying to calculate the magnitude and direction of the force exerted on a wheel when encountering a step. The wheel and the steps are non-deformable.

I found two different approaches:

- energy approach, from which I can calculate the difference in speeds before and after, but I have no idea how to continue from there.
  [Vertical component of force for rigid wheel hitting a step](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/23524/vertical-component-of-force-for-rigid-wheel-hitting-a-step)
- impulse and angular momentum, the procedure described by the user QiLinXue on the bottom of the post bellow roughly makes sense to me, but I have no idea what is the direction of the average force he calculates. I also don't really understand what the velocity change represents.
  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/515895/what-is-the-term-for-shock-absorbed-by-car-suspension

If anyone has any pointers how to continue from here, it would be much appreciated. I'm trying to calculate the vertical force to select the appropriate spring for the given speed.

Comment: As discussed in the second link, I think it might be fruitful to make a drawing and look at the angles to evaluate the impulse that the wheel receives to change its momentum as it strikes the step. I wouldn't necessarily focus on a force but on this impulse, which you might then apply to a model of an inertial mass given a sudden upward velocity that depends on the step size and initial rolling speed.

Comment: Yes, but the problem is that the when the wheel goes over the step, the direction of the speed vector and the force changes during this step up process. What would then be the "average" direction of the force?

Comment: I’d try modeling the effective direction as up. The rigidity that you specify precludes any other direction from having an effect. What are your other options to move forward?

Comment: This is clear, but when using the second, impulse approach, I calculate the time of the force acting on the wheel (time of the impulse) as the time it takes for the wheel to move over the step in a radial arch. The direction of this force changes when the wheel is moving on an arch.